# combobox Value Label not showing properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-combobox

I have a combobox that looks the following
In my JS:

```
timeValue = 7;
options =[
        { label: 'Last 7 days', value: 7},
        { label: 'Last 30 days', value: 30 },
        { label: 'Last Quarter', value: 120 }
    ]

handleChangeTime(event){
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.timeValue = event.target.value;
  
    }
```

in my HTML:

```
<lightning-combobox
              name="Time Frame"
              label="Time Frame"
              value={timeValue}
              placeholder="Select Time Frame"
              options={options}
              onchange={handleChangeTime} 
              dropdown-alignment =left>
</lightning-combobox>
```

When I load my LWC, then the Label is well displayed and show "Last 7 Days"
my issue is when I change it then the Label become "Select Time Frame"

My console.log show me the right value, 7 or 30 or 120 ..

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: in options array provide value in single quotes instead of without quotes.this will solve he issue.  options =[
        { label: 'Last 7 days', value: '7'},
        { label: 'Last 30 days', value: '30' },
        { label: 'Last Quarter', value: '120' }
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation), the onchange event has a string return type

[image]

And the options value you have used is not in single quotes(represented as a string).

Change the `get options()` as shown below, code should work fine.

```
get options() {
       return [ { label: 'Last 7 days', value: '7'},
        { label: 'Last 30 days', value: '30' },
        { label: 'Last Quarter', value: '120' }
      ];
  }
```

Comment: haa ok .. I needed it as a Number to use it in my apex .. 
Lesson learned, it works thank you ;)